# How to solve "no method named `foo` found for mutable reference `&mut Bar<X>` in the current scope"

Tags: rust

I'm working on a generic data structure that will hold pointers to some structs, and using a `Handle` that would normally be held by the struct, will call back into the structure to remove the pointer when the `Handle` is dropped.  I'm unable to come up with a solution that will allow the call from the handle back into the node.  I've tried a few different permutations of trait bound narrowing and associated type hackery with no success...  I'm feeling like the issue is related to some kind of infinite associated type recursion (something like https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23122), but just not sure.  The error is

```
error[E0599]: no method named `remove` found for mutable reference `&mut Node<X>` in the current scope
  --> src/lib.rs:50:15
   |
50 |             m.remove(self.index); // <<----- ???
   |               ^^^^^^ method not found in `&mut Node<X>`
   |
   = note: the method `remove` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `<X as FooTrait>::T = X`
```

```
pub struct Node<T: FooTrait> {
    items: Vec<*mut T>,
}

impl <T: FooTrait<T=T>> Node<T> {
    pub fn new() ->Node<T> {
        Node {
            items: Default::default(),
        }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, item: &mut T) {
        let handle = Handle::new(self,0);
        item.set_handle(handle);
        self.items.push(item);
    }

    pub fn remove(&mut self, index: u16) {
        self.items.swap_remove(index as usize);
    }
}

pub struct Handle<X:FooTrait> {
    node: *mut Node<X>,
    index: u16,
}

impl <T:FooTrait>  Handle<T> {
    fn new(node: &mut Node<T>, i: u16) -> Handle<T> {
        Handle {
            node: node,
            index: i
        }
    }
}

impl <X:FooTrait> Drop for Handle<X>  {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            let m = self.node.as_mut().unwrap();
            m.remove(self.index); // <<----- ???
        }
    }
}

pub trait  FooTrait {
    type T : FooTrait;
    fn set_handle(&mut self, h: Handle<Self::T>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is caused by recursive constraints.

`remove(&mut self, index: u16)` is only defined for types that contain to `T: FooTrait<T=T>`, causing the `FooTrait::T` to reference itself, because `T` is that `FooTrait<T=T>` type.